# Is there a point in unit testing Mongoose schema

Tags: unit-testing, mongoose, schema

For purpose of demonstration assume that I have the following schema + model:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I intend to have a large schema, so for easier maintenance I have it defined in **user.schema.js**, whereas the corresponding **user model** is in a separate file.

I covered the model with unit tests and began contemplating doing the same for the schema module, except... I am not sure if there is a point?

I have seen people test their models/schemas using an actual test database connection, but that is not a unit test IMO, it resembles an integration test more, and that is a different concept. For a unit test of a **schema** only I don't care if MongoDB itself works correctly.

The Internet (including SO) has also revealed code, which tests Mongoose's validation. This is closer to what I wanted to do as the basic idea is to check whether all expected props and restrictions are in the schema. It would look like this:

```
it('should be invalid if username is empty', function(done) {
  new UserModel().validate(function(err) {
    expect(err.errors.name).to.exist;
    done();
  });
});
```

If testing with a live DB one could change `.validate` to `.save` too.

Then it dawned upon me that I would be doing two things here:

1. Testing the behaviour of Mongoose, which I also don't care/intend/want to do.
2. Essentially duplicating my schema. If I later decide to change anything in it, I would have to change the unit test too.

This seems like unit testing a configuration object, and that is pointless, aside from maybe making sure that I wrote my regexes correctly and stuff like that.

### Questions

1. I have thus decided not to test the schema at all. Does that make sense or am I missing something?
2. As a side question, do you believe there is a point in writing tests with a DB connection? This would test my schema + mongoose + mongo and somehow I find it redundant.

Comment: Am asking the same question now that you have :). Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Sadly, I haven't... : [